Gradle conditional resolutionStrategy.force on packages
I have an react native application in my android/app/build.gradle file I have forced the version of lottie for all configurations
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy.force "com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.2"
}

I am using a third party library for example react-native-xyz upon build my application it returns an error
AAPT: error: attribute lottie_clipToCompositionBound not found

but if I comment the resolutionStrategy.force line the build is successful
upon checking the dependency tree for the react-native-xyz I found out this
+--- com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.2.0 -> 6.1.0 (*)

I tried forcing this version on the react-native-xyz package using patch-packge but it did not work
Is there any way I can avoid forcing this version just on the package?
